how do you create a python workspace in moveit from scratch?
I am a beginner, I am trying to setup moveit2 environment to run python code. the website shows the method to create a workspace in C++, how should i alter it for python. should i use ament_python to build the workspace or just ament_cmake and then add packages to packages.xml like moveit_py.
